# Projectile motion; the faster projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Imagine this scenario: Two objects are thrown simultaneously, from $y=0$, with different speeds $u$ and $v$, and at angles $\varphi$ and $\varphi+\theta$. We want to find out which projectile returns to its original position first (i.e $y=0$). When they are both back at it, the distance between them is $\Delta x$, which we assume is positive.

We assume that $\varphi+\theta\leq\pi/2$, and that the angle $\varphi$ is associated to the projectile thrown with speed $u$.

**Given:** $\varphi+\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\Delta x\geq0$.

[image]

For both projectiles, we can express their motion vector like this:
$$\vec r(t)=(v_xt)\hat\imath+(v_yt-\frac{1}{2}gt^2)\hat\jmath$$
If I suppose that $A$'s final position is $x$, then I can find the time like this:
$$t_A=\frac{x}{v\cos(\varphi+\theta)}=\frac{2v}{g}\sin(\varphi+\theta)$$
Doing the same thing for $B$, I get:
$$t_B=\frac{x+\Delta x}{u\cos(\varphi)}=\frac{2u}{g}\sin(\varphi)$$
Taking the difference using the solution from the $y$ coordinates:
$$t_A-t_B=\frac{2}{g}(v\sin(\varphi+\theta)-u\sin(\varphi))$$
I know that $\sin(\varphi+\theta)\geq\sin(\varphi)$, but I have no idea how the velocities are. The quotient of the times can help me, though:
$$\frac{t_A}{t_B}=\frac{v}{u}\frac{\sin(\varphi+\theta)}{\sin(\varphi)}=\frac{x}{x+\Delta x}\frac{u\cos(\varphi)}{v\cos(\varphi+\theta)}$$
which means that:
$$\frac{u^2}{v^2}=\frac{x+\Delta x}{x}\frac{\sin(\varphi+\theta)\cos(\varphi+\theta)}{\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)}
=\frac{x+\Delta x}{x}\frac{\sin\left(2(\varphi+\theta)\right)}{\sin(2\varphi)}\geq1$$
or, in other words, $u\geq v$ and:
$$u=v\sqrt{\frac{x+\Delta x}{x}\frac{\sin\left(2(\varphi+\theta)\right)}{\sin(2\varphi)}}$$
Going back to my orginal time difference:
$$\begin{align*}
t_A-t_B&=\frac{2}{g}(v\sin(\varphi+\theta)-u\sin(\varphi))\\
&=\frac{2}{g}\sin(\varphi)\left(\frac{\sin(\varphi+\theta)}{\sin(\varphi)}v-u\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{g}\sin(\varphi)v\left(\frac{\sin(\varphi+\theta)}{\sin(\varphi)}-\sqrt{\frac{x+\Delta x}{x}\frac{\sin\left(2(\varphi+\theta)\right)}{\sin(2\varphi)}}\right)
\end{align*}$$
But how can I judge the sign of the difference between the parenthesis? Any ideas? Thank you for your time!

Comment: is some data missing.like v>u or v<u or v=u

Comment: you can put data and check which time is more or less depending on missing data i mentioned

Comment: @sarthak hello, I have determined that $u\geq v$ is a must. I think that you have missed that part.

Comment: ohh sorry i read the question only

Comment: Note i think u  want to generalize the situation.But it depends on initial situation like with same initial speed a ball with 30⁰ and 60⁰ will have diffrent range but same time

Comment: You only need to consider vertical displacement under gravity. Whichever rises higher will take longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption that
$$\frac{\sin{(2(\phi+\theta))}}{\sin{(2\phi)}}\geq 1$$
isn't correct.

$$\frac{\sin{(2(50^o+5^o))}}{\sin{(2\cdot 50^o)}}\approx 0,954$$

Galileo postulated that the vertical and horizontal movements are independent and hence in this case it suffices to look at the y direction only (as mentioned in comments).

$$\frac{t_A}{t_B}=\frac{v}{u}\cdot \frac{\sin{(\phi+\theta)}}{\sin{(\phi)}}$$

Correction:

If $\frac{u}{v} > \frac{\sin{(\theta)}}{\sin{(\phi+\theta)}} \Rightarrow t_A\gt t_B$

If $\frac{u}{v} < \frac{\sin{(\theta)}}{\sin{(\phi+\theta)}} \Rightarrow t_A\lt t_B$

Comment: You are correct. Unfortunately, the sin of the double angle terms have been edited later, I made a mistake originally.
So I guess it isn't possible to have a result independent of the speeds?

Comment: @Luyw : My conclusion also had a problem, this is corrected now. You are correct,  to conclude we need to include both the speeds and the angles.